# findbugs performance detector

Tags: java, performance, findbugs

Is there any open source findbugs detectors extensions, espcially for performance bugs, for low-latency? I didn't find any meaningful extension beyond barebone findbugs impl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the code analysis in IntelliJ It has many detections and auto-fixes.

I haven't seen anything for low latency as such.  Usually this means changing the code significantly to minimise the use of locks, or discarding objects.

Using a commercial profiler is the best start. Create some micro-benchmarks for your specific use case.  A code review of the critical path is useful and I would add nano-second time stamps which can be recorded in production see see how long each stage is actually taking. esp if you want less than 100 micro-second latencies.

Comment: Thanks. @Peter-Lawrey I know benchmarking is king in low-latency programming. B-t it's tricky to make it right in the JVM, especially micro one. Do you know any blogs specifically talking about low-latency programming?

Comment: You could have a look at mine. ;) http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk//search/label/Performance

Comment: Your blog is already on my rss feed list :) it's a wonderful read besides martin's, cliff's and dave's. Do you know any other good blogs for me to read more?

Comment: is there a quicker way to get notified about question and answer? In email notif, it's min 3 hr. But it seems you reply instantly.

Comment: When I am on the web site I see there is a message in my "inbox" in the top left.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout if [CodePro Analytix](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/) provides such a feature. Well, this is not a findbugs plugin.